# How to emulate a constructor with ES5 Object.create and object literal syntax?

Tags: javascript, object-create

Presume I have an object like this:

```
var Foo = {
  x: 5,
  sprite: new Image()
}
```

Problem: I want to initialize that sprite with the right src.  However, when I use the following creation technique:

```
var f = Object.create(Foo);
```

I don't have a constructor method (aka init function) to setup `sprite.src = 'cool.png';`

My question:

If I am using the object literal technique, and `Object.create()`, when do I actually initialize some of my internal state (like the example of the `new Image()`)

My solution:

```
var Foo = {
  create: function() {
    var f = Object.create(Foo);
    f.sprite.src = 'cool.png';
    return f;
  }
}
```

However, I don't know if that's a great pattern.  I'd like to do this the "JavaScript Way" if there is a way. :)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you would rather make your code complex than take advantage of the simplicity of object system.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

To cut a long story short: Don't try. The basic idea of Object.create is avoiding constructor functions. You're better off using this good old pattern:

```
var Foo = function (url) {
    //this.sprite.src = url; //  This will overwrite the prototype's src
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = url;
};
Foo.prototype = {
    x: 5,
    sprite: new Image() // do you really want this?
};
```

Then use `new Foo` instead of `Object.create`.

Comment: provide some arguments on why he shouldn't try it please

Comment: @a0viedo Basically because it adds unnecessary confusion to your code. Each `Foo` instance would inherit a `create()` method that creates siblings. Why would anyone want this?

Comment: With this construct, each Foo instance would inherit a create() method that creates children: function create() { return Object.create(this); }

Answer (score 6):

I do something very similar to what you've written above, but I combine it with the module pattern:

```
var Vehicle = (function(){
        var exports = {};
        exports.prototype = {};
        exports.prototype.init = function() {
                this.mph = 5;
        };
        exports.prototype.go = function() {
                console.log("Going " + this.mph.toString() + " mph.");
        };

        exports.create = function() {
                var ret = Object.create(exports.prototype);
                ret.init();
                return ret;
        };

        return exports;
})();
```

From the outside, this exposes `Vehicle.create()` and `Vehicle.prototype`. Then if I want to make a Derived type, I can do this:

```
var Car = (function () {
        var exports = {};
        exports.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
        exports.prototype.init = function() {
                Vehicle.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
                this.wheels = 4;
        };

        exports.create = function() {
                var ret = Object.create(exports.prototype);
                ret.init();
                return ret;
        };

        return exports; 

})();
```

This pattern lets me derive types without making the error of `Car.prototype = new Vehicle()`, which is *fail* if my constructors take parameters.

Answer (score 4):

As I can assume from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) you should do something like:

```
function ImgInstance(src){
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=src;
    return img;
}

Object.create(Foo, {sprite: {value: ImgInstance("url")}});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this article sums it up pretty nicely:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-Object-create-Improves-Constructor-Based-Inheritance-In-Javascript-It-Doesn-t-Replace-It.htm

Comment: In fact this article refers to the following blog post, that actually **does** explain how to emulate constructors with Object.create :
http://www.uxebu.com/blog/2011/02/object-based-inheritance-for-ecmascript-5/

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do this:

```
function Image(src) {
    this.src = src;
}

function Foo() {
    this.x = 5;
    this.sprite = new Image('cool.png');
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this requires the goode olde `new` keyword rather than an `Object.create`, and doesn't create the prototype chain that the OP wants.